# Not able to get the response from django rest api using requests.get() method

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django Rest Application and exposed one service (To get the User List)

Now when I am trying to call  thru curl request, I am able to get the User List.

**curl -v -XGET -i 'http://XXX.XX.XX9.XX1:8000/ebxxx/api/users/'**

But When I try to call it from another app using requests.get() method , I am getting 504 server error:

I am trying :

```
header = {"Content-type":"application/json"}

response = requests.get("http://XXX.XX.XX9.XX1:8000/ebxxx/api/users/", headers=header)
```

Error:

> "response , response<504>"

Comment: 504 response code is [Gateway timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504) error. It's probably something wrong either with connection to web server or with firewall configuration.

Comment: But in my point of view if I am able to get the response thru curl request, It should get   in this case also (If there is any firewall issue , it should not work for curl request too)

Comment: if you could suggest any config changes related to firewall, I can try

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you put extra header in `get()` method, while not adding this header in curl request.

Comment: Yes I tried with both case (removing header and adding header in curl request), it works fine. And the same thing I tried with Django rest method , but still facing the issue

Comment: Have you tried: `request.GET.get('my_value')`

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: @running.t you were right, It was connection issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, It was related to proxy settings.

Actually I am using two VMs (Both have different IPs) with two different micro services (First VM has User Registration service (Add User, Delete User, Get Users) and Second VM has a service to call the User Registration service using django rest framework).

Now VMs are working in a local area network with some network permissions, So I have to set the proxy range and then I have to start the server.

I am using below command for proxy setting before running the Django server:

export no_proxy='my IP/range'

Now it works fine.